# wp_register_sidebar_widget() disappered my Widgets submenu - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: widgets, register-sidebar

Working on a theme made by someone else as an official duty. At first it's causing error in the wp-admin Widgets page — not working at all. Then the first thought came to my mind was debugging...

**Debugging steps**
» Activated `WP_DEBUG`.
» Deactivated all the plugins.
» Switched to default theme 'T13'.

**Errors**
Found that the problem was from the theme. Activated the theme again, and it's showing many DEBUG notices both in front-end and back-end. First of 'em was:

> **`register_sidebar_widget()` is deprecated.**

So without hesitation I went to `wp_register_sidebar_widget()`. But found myself in a claustrophobic arena — I exactly don't know how to register widgets with `wp_register_sidebar_widget`. But with [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_sidebar_widget) and other WP.SE.com threads, I tried the following:

```
<?php
// Register widgetized areas
function theme_widgets_init() {

    // Area 1   
    wp_register_sidebar_widget(
        'primary_widget_area',          //widget_id/ widget_slug
        'Primary Widget Area',          //widget_name
        'primary_widget_display',       //callback function
        array(
            'description' => 'The primary widget on the right side'
        )
    );

    function primary_widget_display( $args ) {

        extract($args);
        echo $before_widget;
        echo $before_title . 'My Unique Widget' . $after_title;
        echo $after_widget;
        // print some HTML for the widget to display here
        echo "Your Widget Test";

    }

    // Area 2

    wp_register_sidebar_widget(
        'secondary_widget_area', //widget_id/ widget_slug
        'Secondary Widget Area', //widget_name
        'secondary_widget_display', //callback function
        array(
            'description' => 'The secondary widget on the right side'
        )
    );

    function secondary_widget_display( $args ) {        
        echo "show the secondary widget";       
    }

} // end theme_widgets_init

add_action( 'init', 'theme_widgets_init' );
?>
```

#### PROBLEM #1:

*The Widgets sub menu under the Appearance menu in wp-admin is totally gone.*

#### PROBLEM #2:

I'm struggling with new `callback_function` of `wp_register_sidebar_widget()`. How can I implement the old sidebar widget design with the new `callback_function`. So, for Primary Widget Area, you can see, I simply copied & pasted the code from Codex to understand how the code is working. But as the **Problem #1** occurred, I'm unable to test em.

Here is the code-block primarily used in the theme, is now deprecated. *How can I use the new `callback_function` to do the same?*

```
<?php
        // Deprecated Codes Below
        register_sidebar_widget(
            array (
                'name' => 'Secondary Widget Area',
                'id' => 'secondary_widget_area',
                'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s" class="widget-container %2$s">',
                'after_widget' => "</li>",
                'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
                'after_title' => '</h3>',
            )
        );
?>
```

> **NOTE:** But the new code I pasted at the top solved one thing — all the DEBUG notices are gone. That's a relief, alHamduLILLAH! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some problems in your code but you are close, some pointers to solve problems.

First, eliminate as much code as you can which still contains the problem. In your case remove the second widget, the less code you have to look at the easier it will be to find the problem.

> In other words use *The SSCCE* : http://sscce.org/

Another piece of advice is to create unique widget id's and prefix your functions, using "Primary" and names like `theme_widgets_init` is not a great idea.

If you do not see any *Widgets* available under *Appearance* in the menu, if the menu item **does not exist** at all, it is because you need at least one active sidebar using `register_sidebar`.

You need at least one of these :

```
 function islam_widgets_sidebar() {
    // Area 1, located at the top of the sidebar.
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name' => __( 'Primary Widget Area'),
        'id' => 'primary-widget-area',
        'description' => __( 'The primary widget area'),
        'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s" class="widget-container %2$s">',
        'after_widget' => '</li>',
        'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title' => '</h3>',
        ) );
      }
  add_action( 'widgets_init', 'islam_widgets_sidebar' );
```

For your actual widget's issue,  you're nesting a function inside another function, the display callback needs to be outside the function.

```
// Register widgetized areas
function islam_theme_widgets() {

    // Area 1
    wp_register_sidebar_widget(
        'mayeenul_widget_area',          //widget_id/ widget_slug
        'Mayeenuls Widget Area',          //widget_name
        'islam_widget_display',       //callback function
        array(
            'description' => 'The primary widget on the right side'
        )
    );

} // end theme_widgets_init

 function islam_widget_display( $args ) {

        extract($args);
        echo $before_widget;
        echo $before_title . 'My Unique Widget' . $after_title;
        echo $after_widget;
        // print some HTML for the widget to display here
        echo "Your Widget Test";

    }

add_action( 'init', 'islam_theme_widgets' );
```

For a second Widget you would do the same but of course with different function callback and id's / names.

**It's really important to note that the above functions are pretty useless because the widget can only be used once in exactly 1 of the sidebars.**

You really want to be extending the `WP_Widget` class:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_widget

Comment: Something is happening out of control. I tried your code, NOT WORKING! I then deleted all other codes from the functions.php and put just the code you offered - NOT WORKING! - NO WIDGETS SUB MENU!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by submenu, the code above shows a widget under `Appearance-->Widgets-->Available Widgets'

Comment: Yes, the "Widgets" under "Appearance" is gone! :(

Comment: I would disable any plugins you have and revert to a default theme on 3.6.1  you should get the following: http://i.imgur.com/wBfo1aR.jpg (The code above is the widget in the third column second one down).

Comment: Oh ya do not delete all the code in a theme's function.php, you need to have at least one sidebar active for a widget to display using `register_sidebar`. I will update my answer gimme 2 minutes.

Comment: O! I got everything! Actually it's a misunderstanding. A plugin was causing the deprecated notice, but I, being panic made change in functions.php in `register_sidebar()` - that had no connection with `wp_register_sidebar_widget()`. What `wp_register_sidebar_widget()` done is to create a new **Widget** - not a sidebar. I'm afraid, it's totally my fault. I corrected myself. Thank you very much Wyck for your kind support in time. :)